# Transfer ownership Personal Drive data to Google Workspace Business Shared Drive

Tags: google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

Before the possibility of Google Suite Team Drives / Google Workspace Shared Drives we started using a specific GSuite Account (AccountB) that is owner of the data. We now want to transfer it to Workspace Shared Drives. I can easily transfer folders and files that are owned by an account in our domain (DomainA). However, many files are owned by non-domain accounts (AccountC):

- DomainA

  - Shared Drive
- DomainA

  - AccountB

    - Directory1

      - Directory2 (owned by AccountC, personal account)
      - Directory3 (owned by AccountB)

---

#### I tried to move all the files as AccountB to the shared Drive.

`Partially copies files and directories (only when files are owned by AccountB). So only Directory1 is being copied.`

#### I tried to change the owner from AccountC to Account B.

`Sorry, cannot transfer ownership to AccountB. Ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same domain as the current owner.`

#### I tried using Google Drive File Stream to copy files from Directory2 to Shared Drive

`Unable to create Google Sheets/Docs using Google Drive File stream`

---

My only option left but would require a lot of time is to Download Directory1 and upload it to the Shared Drive. However, this should be done easier right?

Comment: The workaround, however time-consuming, was to just download the whole Directory1 and upload it to the Shared Drive. Still waiting for a permanent solution